# convert object of object to array of objects and iterate the text

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have JSON Objects, I want to convert it to array and iterate to each of text

Here is JSON Object:

```
"dataObject":{
  "object2":{
    "id":"123456",
    "userId":"76890",
    "name":"home"
    }
   }
```

Here is the view.jsx

```
<div>
<p>id:{id}</p>
<p>userId:{userId}</p>
<p>name:{name}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve]. If this is for React you can use [the guide here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002) to create a little snippet. (I would look at [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries) though).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Object.values` to grab the values of your `dataObject` and map through those values

```
function App() {
  const dataObject = {
    object1: {
      id: "3123456",
      userId: "476890",
      name: "1home"
    },
    object2: {
      id: "123456",
      userId: "76890",
      name: "home"
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.values(dataObject).map(({ id, userId, name }) => (
        <div>
          <p>id:{id}</p>
          <p>userId:{userId}</p>
          <p>name:{name}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Demo:

[image: Edit dry-night-uwwmk1]